# Set variables to "Nothing" is a good practice?

Tags: vb.net, memory

If I got

```
Dim myRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0,0,100,100)
```

Is it *necessary* or just *fine* to later do this:

```
myRect = Nothing
```

Or it isn't necessary? Thank you.

**IF** it is necessary, are there other cases it isn't for my variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, as [Joel said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820952/set-variables-to-nothing-is-a-good-practice/4820976#4820976), it's unnecessary.

In your specific example, though, it is actually **pointless**. `Rectangle` is a *value type*, so setting it to `Nothing` is not *even* affecting an object's reference count; it's assigning a new *value* (the default value for `Rectangle`) to your `myRect` variable. This is analogous to having an `Integer` variable and setting it to `0` at the end of a method. Doesn't buy you anything.

---

I should point out that the claim "Setting any variable to `Nothing` [or `null` in C#] never accomplishes anything"* is a myth. It is entirely possible that you may have a *field* in a class which you might as well set to `null` if the object referenced is no longer needed but you still have a reference to the class instance itself.

As a simplistic example, suppose you had some container class which wraps a `T[]` array, and you give this container an `Empty` method. It might make sense to set the container's internal array to `null` in this method, which would result in zero references to the array object, qualifying it for garbage collection. (You would then create a new array when external code next tried to add a `T` to the collection.) If you did not set the field to null on `Empty`, then there would still be a reference to the array (i.e., the field), and so that would be a small amount of memory being used that you really don't need.

Like I said, that's a simplistic example. And honestly, it's rare that you ever need to consider scenarios like that. I just thought I would mention it so that you don't get the wrong impression that setting a *field* to `Nothing` literally never accomplishes anything.

<sub>*I'm not actually quoting anyone specific here; this is just an over-generalization I've heard stated more than once.</sub>

Comment: What if it was an Image type variable?

Comment: @Omega: Then Joel's answer applies (`Image` is a reference type). Setting it to `null` per se is not really valuable. On the other hand, `Image` implements `IDisposable` so you *should* take care to dispose of it properly (by calling `Dispose` or, better, wrapping the variable in a `using` block outside of which you no longer need it).

Answer (score 5):

Don't do it.  This was important to do in the vb6 days, but for .Net it's possible (though very unlikely) for it to actually throw the garbage collector off and have other unexpected side effects.

Comment: with this statement:

but for .Net it's possible (though very unlikely) for it to actually throw the garbage collector off and have other unexpected side effects.

You're actually questioning the very foundations of .net. I highly doubt this is the case.