# Is it compulsory to RemoveEventHandler in Dispose() Mothod, Or ClassObject = Nothing is sufficient

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, destructor, dispose

I have declared few WithEvent handlerr like

**`Private WithEvents mErrorList As ErrorList`**

**`Private WithEvents mControlManager As ControlManager`**

I used this handler to subscribe the events in a class such as

```
    Private Sub mControlManager_PageLoaded(sender As Object, e As DataEntry.PageLoadEventArgs) Handles mControlManager.PageLoaded
      // line of code
    End Sub

Similar way....

        Private Sub mErrorList_ErrorSelected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ErrorSelectedEventArgs) Handles mErrorList.ErrorSelected
       // line of code
       End Sub
```

but in dispose method

```
 Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then                   
             Me.mErrorList = Nothing    
             Me.mControlManager = Nothing
           End If
    End If
    Me.disposedValue = True
   End Sub
```

In the dispose method I set the objects as equal to **Nothing.** 
So my question do I need to remove above the Handler in **Dispose() method or object = Nothing is sufficient.** in such a way

```
 Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
     If Not Me.disposedValue Then
       If disposing Then
        RemoveHandler Me.mErrorList.ErrorSelected, AddressOf Me.mErrorList_ErrorSelected                
        Me.mErrorList = Nothing
        RemoveHandler Me.mControlManager.PageLoaded, AddressOf mControlManager_PageLoaded    
        Me.mControlManager = Nothing
      End If
    End If
    Me.disposedValue = True
   End Sub
```

Comment: None of this code is correct.  Use the Dispose method only to call the Dispose method of any fields in your class, if they have one.

Comment: @HansPassant I have just add code for understanding to the other SO user. my question is do I used RemoveHandler In Dispose() or not.  while  I am setting a values to nothing  of  class object(variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few questions in here, so I will paraphrase and answer one by one.

> Do I need to Call RemoveHandler when creating object declared
>   WithEvents

No

> Do I need to Dispose of objects in the Dispose method

If any objects you are using implement `IDisposable` *and* you are **not** wrapping then in a `Using` block then *your* class should also implement `IDisposable` and call `Dispose` on each of these objects

More Info: [Using block vs IDisposabe.Dispose()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984336/using-block-vs-idisposabe-dispose)

> Do I need to set each object = Nothing in the Dispose method

No

More info: [Set variables to "Nothing" is a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820952/set-variables-to-nothing-is-a-good-practice)